# Android custom button with text beside it

Tags: android, button

I'm trying to create a custom button with text beside it. I'm going to have a list of items with a (x) beside them, so the user can hit the (x) to delete the item. Like this...

(x)Item1  (x)Item2  (x)Item3

I have a class that extends button, but I'm not sure what methods I'm supposed to override, because when I create a button using the custom class, it shows up as a normal button. Here's my code.

```
public class LabelButton extends Button {
  private final Context context;

  private final String label;

  public LabelButton( Context context, String label ) {
    super( context );
    this.context = context;
    this.label = label;
  }

  public View getView( View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View labelView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.label, parent, false );
    TextView textView = (TextView) labelView.findViewById( R.id.label );
    Button button = (Button) labelView.findViewById( R.id.buttonCancel );
    textView.setText( "X" );
    return labelView;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override onDraw method and constructor with Attrs params

```
 public LabelButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
             super(context, attrs, defStyle); 
              if (attrs != null) {
              // set your attrs
         }
        }

 @Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     Paint textPaint = new Paint();
     textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
     textPaint.setColor(textColor);
     textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
     Rect bounds = new Rect();       
     textPaint.getTextBounds(totalText, 0, totalText.length(), bounds);
     int x = getWidth() / 2 - bounds.centerX();
     int y = getHeight() / 2 - bounds.centerY();
     canvas.drawText(text, getLeft(), y, textPaint);// draw your text in coords
}

public synchronized void setText(String text) {
     if (text != null) {
         this.text = text;
     } else {
         this.text = "";
     }
     postInvalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom view that extends LinearLayout, then inflate a xml with a horizontal LinearLayout containing a Button and a TextView. I suggest creating styled attributes like [this tutorial](http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/10/28/custom-views-and-layouts-in-android-os-sdk) for customization.